# If statement on data retrieved from linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So lets say I'm retrieving some data with a linq query as so:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext    

using(db)
{
    var test = from t in db.table1
               where t.col1 == Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value)
               select new
               {
                  t.col2,
                  t.col3
               };
}
```

I then want to check if a condition is not true like:

```
if (col3 != something){ }
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your check is supposed to be done in sql, then the answer by Dave Markle must suit you.
If you want to apply this check on some of the returned entities, it should look somewhat like this:

1. get your objects through `foreach`:

   `foreach(var o in test)
   {

       if(o.col3!= something)
       {
           ...
       }
   }`
2. or use linq to objects:

   `test.ToList().Where(o=>o.col3!=something);`

Comment: I wanted to apply it to a returned entity and this answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext    

using(db)
{
    var test = from t in db.table1
               where t.col1 == Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value)
               select new
               {
                  t.col2,
                  CandyType = (t.col3 == "fudge") ? "It's Fudge" : "It's some other candy!"
               };
```

Though with the Entity Framework you may run into problems with the framework not being able to translate the conditional statement into SQL.  I believe it depends on exactly what actions you perform inside the conditional statement, but it's been a while since I touched EF.  If it turns out that it can't translate the conditional statement into SQL, you'll have to materialize the result by calling .ToList() or .ToArray() and then execute the conditional.